# How to generate license file

Tags: java, security, cryptography

We are making a product which written in Java. We need to generate a license to block the customer from using it on more than one computer.

My question is simple: I need to generate a license file with the product. I would like to know how the file should be, whether its the combination of MAC address, host ID or how it should be.

Comment: How to end copyright. What a question.

Comment: License file is generated before the user installs the app, so you won't have any idea about the MAC address, host id etc !

Comment: There is just no way. In History enterprises tried dongles, mac-adresses and online-checks. Have a look at the existing mechanichms. Take one whos work-effort-balacne is ok.

Comment: @Rakesh Before we sell the product, we get the MAC address and host ID from client for his computer.Okay if not, how the file should be..?

Comment: You should take a look at this QA
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10548510/how-to-create-license-for-my-java-software

Answer (score 0):

The others, especially linked QA, gave good answers. I'll add that many copyright enforcing groups are turning to putting traceable "watermarks" in their content and simply suing infringing groups. The advantage of this approach, if done right, is you don't annoy legitimate users. They don't even notice what you're doing.

However, this is only a way to punish theft or recover costs: you're not going to stop determined software pirates from stealing your stuff with a software trick. You'd have to run the software on a dedicated, tamperproof device. And I doubt many users will pay for that. ;)